# Extending org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, osgi

Im trying to make an servlet extension to org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets extension point, but cant get it working. Ill try to write down my proccess so maybe someone can tell me what im doing wrong or what i didnt do :)

So, first i made just a jetty server with a default servlet.

Here was my initial pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myserver</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <bundle.symbolicName>myserver</bundle.symbolicName>
        <bundle.namespace>com.example</bundle.namespace>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${bundle.namespace}.myserver.App</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.osgi.framework,
                            javax.servlet,
                            javax.servlet.http,
                            org.eclipse.jetty.server,
                            org.eclipse.jetty.servlet
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Require-Bundle>
                        </Require-Bundle>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my App thats a bundle activator:

```
package com.example.myserver;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class App implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler c = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
        c.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloWorldServlet()),"/test");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }   
}
```

And here is my servlet:

```
package com.example.myserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello from HelloWorldServlet");
    }
}
```

Then i launch my configuration with following bundles:

```
javax.servlet,
org.apache.felix.gogo.command,
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,
org.eclipse.equinox.console,
org.eclipse.jetty.continuation,
org.eclipse.jetty.http,
org.eclipse.jetty.io,
org.eclipse.jetty.security,
org.eclipse.jetty.server,
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,
org.eclipse.jetty.util,
org.eclipse.osgi
```

Now when i type in url `http://localhost:8080/test` then everything works fine and my hello text appears.

Now i try to do the same thing with an extension of org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets.

Here is what i do:

1) Add org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry to Require-Bundle under pom.xml

2) open manifest, select extensions tab, click add, select org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets extension point, add, under extension details put class com.example.myserver.HelloWorldServlet and /test2 as alias.

Following plugin.xml is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
      <servlet
            alias="/test2"
            class="com.example.myserver.HelloWorldServlet">
      </servlet>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Under launch configuration I needed to add these bundles:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry
org.eclipse.osgi.service,
org.eclipse.osgi.services,
org.eclipse.equinox.common,
org.eclipse.equinox.registry,
javax.xml
```

Then when i run my configuration i get a warning: `!MESSAGE The extensions and extension-points from the bundle "myserver" are ignored. The bundle is not marked as singleton.`

... so in pom.xml i change to this:

```
<Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName};singleton:=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
```

... run again, no errors, everything seems nice.

If i run `http://localhost:8080/test` everything works.
If i run `http://localhost:8080/test1` i get an **not found** error.

Maybe i left something undone?
I hope i didnt go into too much detail, but i really hope someone can help me figure this out. Thanks! :)

Comment: In your first example, you do server.start() and then server.join(). I believe that join() blocks the calling thread until the server shuts down. That is a really REALLY bad thing to do in a BundleActivator start method... you steal the thread of the launcher and will actually prevent the OSGi framework from starting properly.

Comment: Thank you for anwsering, i removed join but the problem still remains. Could you see anything else wrong with my code or workflow?

Comment: Not really but I'm not familiar with this extension point. However I wonder why are you trying to do this with an extension point at all? It seems like so much more work than just publishing your Servlet as a service and using the Felix [HTTP Whiteboard](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#using-the-whiteboard) bundle

Comment: Ok, i got i working. Seems that i was doing something really-really wrong (and stupid :)). I didnt need to start a jetty server myself at all. Here was the tutorial that helped me: http://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/osgi-as-a-web-application-server/. 
Only sidenote that org.mortbay.jetty bundle mentioned in the end has changed to org.eclipse.jetty. Anyway as i understand one of the included bundles somehow starts a jetty server for me and all i have to do is write an extension and point to my servlet. How/where exactly the jetty server starts i have no idea, but ill try to find out.

Comment: Try: http://localhost:8080/test2 instead of http://localhost:8080/test1. I don't know wether this is just a typo so I post this as a comment only.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced, because described alias="/test2", and
try with http://localhost:8080/test1

You should use http://localhost:8080/test2